# thmtools breaks links to algorithms

Tags: algorithmicx, thmtools

I don't know why, but loading `thmtools` breaks the links to the algorithm. Just removing this package, or loading after the `\numberwithin` stuff seems to fix the compilation, but I'm wondering if it is a known issue, and if removing/moving it at a random different line is the correct way to fix this issue.

MWE: (to test, just click on the second link on the last page: you'll go to the wrong theorem)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, amsmath}

%% thmtools is the problem with numberwithin{algorithm}{section}!
\usepackage{thmtools}


\usepackage{algorithm, algorithmicx, algpseudocode}
\floatname{algorithm}{Protocol}
\providecommand*\algorithmautorefname{Protocol}
\numberwithin{algorithm}{section}


\begin{document}

\section{Section with links}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{I am an algorithm that attracts all the links} \label{protocol:firstProtocol}
  I attract all the link...
\end{algorithm}

\newpage
\section{Section with no links}


\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Nobody wants to link me :(} \label{protocol:secondProtocol}
Please link to me!!
\end{algorithm}


\newpage

Le premier est \autoref{protocol:firstProtocol} et le deuxième est \autoref{protocol:secondProtocol}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With very few exceptions `hyperref` is **always** the last package to be loaded (it has to redefine a lot of other packages, so needs to see that they have been loaded).

Moving `hyperref` down, and both links hit their right targets for me.